# Mock response.text in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to get a response from API with below code. I get the result and printing it as `response.text`. For the same, I try to write unit test. I am able to mock the API response with JSON content. But I get error as below while running unit test.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

def get_call():
   url = 'https://test/api/v1'
   username = 'NTdasj'
   pwd = '3214234'

   response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, pwd))
   data = json.loads(response.text)
   print(data)
```

Tried Unit test code:

```
from get_api import get_call
from mock import patch
import os
import sys
import json
testdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(testdir)))


resp = {
  "success": True,
  "message": "Data exist",
  "data": []
 }
response = json.dumps(resp)
newresponse = json.loads(response)

@patch('get_api.requests.get')
def test_get_call(get):
   get.side_effect = [newresponse]
   get_call()
```

Comment: You don't show the test, so it's impossible to say what's wrong with it, beyond that your mock returns a tuple not a real or test doubled response object. Give a [mcve]. For what it's worth, I've used [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) for this kind of thing in the past.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have included the tried unit test code

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking `requests.get` to produce a `dict`, not an object whose `text` attribute is a JSON encoding of a `dict`.

```
get.return_value.text = response
```

Comment: This is not clear. Can you clarify?